# replace method mechanism

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server

i face the following problem::

i wanna to escape the following character ' single quote:

it works when making this test through :the built in method `Replace("'","''");`

as this code below :(just a test) it works

```
protected void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            lbl.Text = string.Empty;
            SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(Constr);`

            SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO details VALUES('" + txt.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + txt.Text.Replace("'", "''")+ "')", mycon);

            mycon.Open();
            int affectedRows = 0;

            affectedRows = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mycon.Close();
        }
```

but i wanna to generalize my solution to work all over the application through my Insert method in the data access layer:

```
public static int InsertEntity(string tblName, Dictionary<string, string> dtParams)
        {
            int Result = -1;
            DBConnection DAL_Helper = new DBConnection("");
            string[] field_names = new string[dtParams.Count];
            dtParams.Keys.CopyTo(field_names, 0);
            string[] field_values = new string[dtParams.Count];
            dtParams.Values.CopyTo(field_values, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < field_values.Length; i++)
            {
                field_values[i].Replace("'", "''");
            }
            string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO " + tblName + " (" + string.Join(",", field_names) + ") values ('" + string.Join("','", field_values) + "')";

            Result = DAL_Helper.Execute_NonQuery(insertCmd);
            return Result;
        }
```

this not escaping the ' single quote charecter,although i use  `Replace("'","''");`

what is the problem ,,how to fix this problem?

Comment: Note: If you use stored procedure or Entity Framework there will not be any problem of sql injection. Quote is not the only character there can be others like '[','%' etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly recommend you use `Command Parameters` using `SqlCommand.Parameters` collection instead of your approach.

Problem is here :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < field_values.Length; i++)
        {
            field_values[i].Replace("'", "''");
        }
```

Replace it with :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < field_values.Length; i++)
        {
            field_values[i] = field_values[i].Replace("'", "''");
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I read that. In you second code, change the loop code as mentioned above. `String.Replace()` method does not change the string it is called on but returns changed string.

Comment: u recommend Command Parameters over (SqlCommand.Parameters collection.) because of avoiding sql injection or what?

Comment: `Command Parameters` is a concept and `SqlCommand.Parameters` is an implementation of it in ADO.NET. And yes, one of the reasons has to do with avoiding SQL Injection.

Comment: sorrry one more question i wanna to do the thing with value in data dictionary .` for (int i = 0; i < dtParams.Count; i++)
            {
                
                dtParams.Values.ElementAt(i).Replace("'", "''");
             
            }`

Comment: i cannot do any assignment here..the dtParams is a Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Building on decyclone's answer.  CommandParameters are the way to go here, you are just re-inventing it with your own code.

I have found a very nice clear example here for supplying params to a SQL statement.

http://dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

```
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dogs1 WHERE Name LIKE @Name", connection))
        {
            string dogName = "Mc'Dougal";
            //
            // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
            //
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", dogName));
            //
            // Read in the SELECT results.
            //
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        }
```